# LVM and Gparted not allowing me to resize partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted, lvm

I'm looking to resize my ubuntu partition (/dev/sda2) and tried first shrinking the Logical Volume through lvm and then the physical volume through both lvm and gparted. While shrinking the logical volume worked, shrinking the physical volume did not.

This was on an Ubuntu 18.04 bootable usb.

Attached are the outputs of my physical volumes, logical volumes, and gparted, as well as the error I get while trying to resize. My understanding is that the swap logical volume at the end of the partition is what is preventing this. Can anyone explain what this is used for, whether I need it, and whether I could move it to another location on the disks to shrink my partition?

```
--- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/ubuntu-vg/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                ubuntu-vg
  LV UUID                YdBCyk-CZ4x-o9MW-r50e-2pPv-AVCM-4UTwLU
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time ubuntu, 2018-06-23 23:36:52 -0400
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                359.30 GiB
  Current LE             91981
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:0

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/ubuntu-vg/swap_1
  LV Name                swap_1
  VG Name                ubuntu-vg
  LV UUID                oXl52b-jhwl-5YVm-LDux-Od0N-7uXs-Y1FpyE
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time ubuntu, 2018-06-23 23:36:52 -0400
  LV Status              available
  # open                 2
  LV Size                980.00 MiB
  Current LE             245
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:1

  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda2
  VG Name               ubuntu-vg
  PV Size               <465.26 GiB / not usable 2.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes 
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              119106
  Free PE               26880
  Allocated PE          92226
  PV UUID               85nOEc-rewk-yNNR-tQms-Pk4W-ax4X-5fLYmX
```

#

```
  sudo lvm pvresize -v --setphysicalvolumesize 387361792K /dev/sda2

    Wiping internal VG cache
    Wiping cache of LVM-capable devices
    Archiving volume group "ubuntu-vg" metadata (seqno 7).

/dev/sda2: Requested size <369.42 GiB is less than real size 465.26 GiB. Proceed?  [y/n]: y
    Accepted input: [y]
  WARNING: /dev/sda2: Pretending size is 774723584 not 975722496 sectors.
    Resizing volume "/dev/sda2" to 774723584 sectors.
    Resizing physical volume /dev/sda2 from 119106 to 94570 extents.
  /dev/sda2: cannot resize to 94570 extents as later ones are allocated.
  0 physical volume(s) resized / 1 physical volume(s) not resized
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please copy and paste those texts!

Comment: Hi George, do you mean copy and paste the output of the linked pictures? Are they coming up as blocked? I apologize for my ignorance on the subject; this is my first time posting a question on the forum.

Comment: Text on images aren't allowed, please copy it from the terminal and paste it into your question!

Comment: Just updated it! My thoughts were to delete the swap partition at the end of the drive, shrink the root partition, then create a new swap partition right after that, and then have the allocated free space at the end. However, I don't know if this is safe or correct.

Comment: This should be helpful https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67702/how-to-reduce-volume-group-size-in-lvm!

Comment: Yep; you want `pvmove` as outlined in that answer.